# Sonar server not starting after upgrading to version 5.3

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

I am coding a plugin and I have upgraded my Sonarqube version and it is now not starting if I try to start with the basic reference plugin provided by Maven.

The log file says:

```
            --> Wrapper Started as Service
        Launching a JVM...
        Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
          Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
    2016.02.03 17:20:45 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\anupama_vijjapu\Downloads\sonarqube-5.3\sonarqube-5.3\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Users\anupama_vijjapu\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process381919358947815193properties
    2016.02.03 17:20:45 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
    2016.02.03 17:20:45 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
    2016.02.03 17:20:45 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1454500245101] version[1.7.2], pid[7400], build[e43676b/2015-09-14T09:49:53Z]
    2016.02.03 17:20:45 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1454500245101] initializing ...
    2016.02.03 17:20:45 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1454500245101] loaded [], sites []
    2016.02.03 17:20:45 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1454500245101] using [1] data paths, mounts [[OS Disk (C:)]], net usable_space [50.5gb], net total_space [99.9gb], types [NTFS]
    2016.02.03 17:20:46 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
    2016.02.03 17:20:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1454500245101] initialized
    2016.02.03 17:20:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1454500245101] starting ...
    2016.02.03 17:20:47 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1454500245101] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}
    2016.02.03 17:20:47 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1454500245101] sonarqube/y0rSbAteR7S21ega2TGBDA
    2016.02.03 17:20:50 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1454500245101] new_master [sonar-1454500245101][y0rSbAteR7S21ega2TGBDA][HJD23095][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1454500245101}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
    2016.02.03 17:20:50 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1454500245101] started
    2016.02.03 17:20:50 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1454500245101] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
    2016.02.03 17:20:50 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
    2016.02.03 17:20:50 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx768m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\anupama_vijjapu\Downloads\sonarqube-5.3\sonarqube-5.3\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;C:\Users\anupama_vijjapu\Downloads\sonarqube-5.3\sonarqube-5.3\lib\jdbc\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\anupama_vijjapu\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process6514377188590834111properties
    2016.02.03 17:20:51 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
    2016.02.03 17:20:51 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp] Webapp directory: C:\Users\anupama_vijjapu\Downloads\sonarqube-5.3\sonarqube-5.3\web
    2016.02.03 17:20:51 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
    2016.02.03 17:20:51 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    2016.02.03 17:20:52 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1454500245101] loaded [], sites []
    2016.02.03 17:20:52 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.3 / 8db783e62b266eeb0d0b10dc050a7ca50e96c5d1
    2016.02.03 17:20:52 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
    2016.02.03 17:20:54 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: C:\Users\anupama_vijjapu\Downloads\sonarqube-5.3\sonarqube-5.3
    2016.02.03 17:20:54 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Findbugs / 2.4 / a334be36ba4374bb779255272c53fb08675ac2c2
    2016.02.03 17:20:54 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Java / 2.8 / 20a3d682b1334eb1857e7bc8a40e11f04fed9528
    2016.02.03 17:20:54 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Motion Chart / 1.7 / e9c4a5c95c75564b3c3b5a887b63ef50fc59a156
    2016.02.03 17:20:54 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin My Sonar plugin / 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    2016.02.03 17:20:54 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to instantiate class [extractimport.SamplePlugin] of plugin [thirdpartypackages]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.PluginLoader.instantiatePluginClasses(PluginLoader.java:146) ~[sonar-core-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.PluginLoader.load(PluginLoader.java:73) ~[sonar-core-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginRepository.loadInstances(ServerPluginRepository.java:274) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginRepository.start(ServerPluginRepository.java:108) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$1.start(ComponentContainer.java:291) ~[sonar-core-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:131) ~[sonar-core-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:214) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel2Container(Platform.java:180) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:91) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:42) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/api/Plugin
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:125) ~[sonar-classloader-1.0.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76) ~[sonar-classloader-1.0.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.PluginLoader.instantiatePluginClasses(PluginLoader.java:141) ~[sonar-core-5.3.jar:na]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.api.Plugin
        at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39) ~[sonar-classloader-1.0.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87) ~[sonar-classloader-1.0.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76) ~[sonar-classloader-1.0.jar:na]
        ... 46 common frames omitted
    2016.02.03 17:20:54 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_45-b18 [Windows 7-amd64]
    2016.02.03 17:20:54 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
    2016.02.03 17:20:58 ERROR web[jruby.rack] initialization failed
    org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.getContainer(Platform.java:282) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.getContainer(JRubyFacade.java:342) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.get(JRubyFacade.java:82) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.getDatabase(JRubyFacade.java:213) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_EVAL(ASTInterpreter.java:95) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.evalWithBinding(ASTInterpreter.java:184) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.evalCommon(RubyKernel.java:1156) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.eval(RubyKernel.java:1114) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$3$eval.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$3$eval.gen) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:180) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:296) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:72) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.FCallManyArgsNode.interpret(FCallManyArgsNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.AttrAssignOneArgNode.interpret(AttrAssignOneArgNode.java:33) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:88) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(ASTInterpreter.java:121) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.runInterpreter(Ruby.java:838) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.loadFile(Ruby.java:2727) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.ExternalScript.load(ExternalScript.java:66) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.load.LoadService.load(LoadService.java:359) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.loadCommon(RubyKernel.java:1107) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(RubyKernel.java:1094) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$1$load.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$1$load.gen) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:210) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:206) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.ast.RootNode.interpret(RootNode.java:129) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_ROOT(ASTInterpreter.java:121) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.evalScriptlet(Ruby.java:419) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.Ruby.evalScriptlet(Ruby.java:396) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.rails.RailsRackApplicationFactory.createApplicationObject(RailsRackApplicationFactory.java:22) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.DefaultRackApplicationFactory.getApplication(DefaultRackApplicationFactory.java:111) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.SharedRackApplicationFactory.doInit(SharedRackApplicationFactory.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:94) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
    2016.02.03 17:20:58 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Error listenerStart
    2016.02.03 17:20:58 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
    2016.02.03 17:20:58 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
     java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
     com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
    2016.02.03 17:20:58 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [JRubyJIT-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    2016.02.03 17:20:58 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [JRubyJIT-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    2016.02.03 17:20:58 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
    2016.02.03 17:20:58 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
    2016.02.03 17:20:58 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
    2016.02.03 17:20:58 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isReady(EmbeddedTomcat.java:83) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isReady(WebServer.java:47) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:80) ~[sonar-process-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:68) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    2016.02.03 17:20:58 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
    2016.02.03 17:21:00 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
    2016.02.03 17:21:00 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
    2016.02.03 17:21:00 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
    2016.02.03 17:21:00 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopping
    2016.02.03 17:21:00 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
    2016.02.03 17:21:00 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1454500245101] stopping ...
    2016.02.03 17:21:00 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1454500245101] stopped
    2016.02.03 17:21:00 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1454500245101] closing ...
    2016.02.03 17:21:00 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1454500245101] closed
    2016.02.03 17:21:00 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[search] is stopped
    <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

What am I missing after upgrading? Is there some change that I have to make in the pom file of the reference plugin to make it compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following message in the stack trace tends to tell that you have plugins that are incompatible with SonarQube 5.3:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/api/Plugin
```

You should check the [Plugin Version Matrix page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+version+matrix) to verify the compatibility of your plugins. If you have custom plugins or plugins not listed on this page, I suggest you to remove them and reinstall one by one to find the faulty one(s).

Comment: Yes Fabrice...removed the incompatible plugin and problem resolved..thanks!